# ¿Cómo encontrar el punto más cercano de una lista A en una lista B?

Tags: python, matemáticas, optimización

Tengo dos conjuntos A y B de puntos con coordenadas geográficas (latitud y longitud). El problema consiste en encontrar para todos los puntos A calcular la distancia mínima a cualquier punto B.

Lo que he intentado es sacar todas las distancias de los puntos A contra todos los puntos B y después encontrar la mínima, pero creo que mi respuesta es computacionalmente muy tardada (he incorrecta). Los datos reales en A son 37508 y para B son 53340.

```
import pandas as pd 
a = {'A': ["A1", "A2","A3"], 'longitud': [19, 25, 34], "latitud": [-99, -100, -120]}
b = {'B': ["B1", "B2","B3"], 'longitud': [17.5, 23.2, 25.8], "latitud": [-100.2, -96, -98.3]}
A = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
B = pd.DataFrame(data=b)

def distancia_i_j(i, j):
    return float(np.sqrt((A[A.A==i].longitud.values-B[B.B==j].longitud.values)**2 + 
                (A[A.A==i].latitud.values-B[B.B==j].latitud.values)**2))

for i in A.A:
    y = [] 
    for j in B.B:
        y.append(distancia_i_j(i,j))
    A.loc[A.A==i, "distancia_min"] = min(y)
```

Estaba pensando en tratar con diagramas de Voronoi y segmentar el espacio con los puntos B, y así ya tener que punto de B estan cerca de A, pero sigo sin tenerlo tan claro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sin ninguna heurística, usando tu misma aproximación de fuerza bruta puedes conseguir una mejora muy importante en tiempo de ejecución vectorizando la operación con NumPy y prescindiendo de bucles:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd


a = {'A': ["A1", "A2","A3"], 'longitud': [19, 25, 34], "latitud": [-99, -100, -120]}
b = {'B': ["B1", "B2","B3"], 'longitud': [17.5, 23.2, 25.8], "latitud": [-100.2, -96, -98.3]}
df_a = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
df_b = pd.DataFrame(data=b)


df_a["distancia_min"] = np.min(np.sqrt(
    (df_a.longitud.to_numpy()[:, np.newaxis] - df_b.longitud.to_numpy()) ** 2 + 
    (df_a.latitud.to_numpy()[:, np.newaxis] - df_b.latitud.to_numpy()) ** 2
    ), axis=1)
```

> ```
> >>> df_a
>     A  longitud  latitud  distancia_min
> 0  A1        19      -99       1.920937
> 1  A2        25     -100       1.878829
> 2  A3        34     -120      23.197629
> ```

La clave está en usar `np.newaxis` para que reste cada elemento de la columna del primer dataframe por todos los elementos del segundo. Es realmente un alias para `None` y nos permite convertir nuestra columna (array 1D) en un array 2D:

```
>>> df_a.longitud.to_numpy()
array([19, 25, 34])

>>> df_a.longitud.to_numpy()[:, np.newaxis]
[[19]
 [25]
 [34]]
```

Si no tienes problemas con usar [scipy](/questions/tagged/scipy), `scipy.spatial.distance.cdist` te calcula las distancias para cada punto directamente:

```
from scipy import spatial

df_a["distancia_min"] = np.min(spatial.distance.cdist(
    df_a[["longitud", "latitud"]], df_b[["longitud", "latitud"]]
    ), axis=1)
```