# Como buscar distancias mínimas, a partir de dos listas de puntos coordenados?

Tags: python, lista

Se tienen dos listas de puntos coordenados (A y B) como se muestra en la imagen, a los cuales se le obtuvo la distancia, a partir de dos puntos, el resultado tal como se muestra:

> ('A1', 'B1', 3.605551275463989) ('A1', 'B2', 1.4142135623730951)
>   ('A1', 'B3', 5.830951894845301) ('A1', 'B4', 1.4142135623730951)
>   ('A1', 'B5', 6.862215385719104) ('A1', 'B6', 6.708203932499369) ('A1',
>   'B7', 3.1622776601683795) ('A1', 'B8', 3.605551275463989) ('A1', 'B9',
>   4.47213595499958) ('A2', 'B1', 5.0) ('A2', 'B2', 4.47213595499958) ('A2', 'B3', 2.0) ('A2', 'B4', 2.8284271247461903) ('A2', 'B5',
>   2.624880949681337) ('A2', 'B6', 3.0) ('A2', 'B7', 4.0) ('A2', 'B8', 1.0) ('A2', 'B9', 1.4142135623730951)

Para el calculo de la distancia:

```
sh_dist = []
for row in sh_distance:
    Ida = (row[0][0])
    Idb = (row[1][0])
    x1 = float(row[0][1])
    x2 = float(row[1][1])
    y1 = float(row[0][2])
    y2 = float(row[1][2])
    dif_x = float(x2-x1)
    dif_y = float(y2-y1)
    sh_d = (math.sqrt(((dif_x)**2)+((dif_y)**2)))
    list = (Ida,Idb,sh_d)
    print (list)
    sh_dist.append(list)
```

segun estos resultados, lo que quiero obtener es:
('A1', 'B2', 1.4142135623730951)
('A1', 'B4', 1.4142135623730951)
('A2', 'B8', 1.0)

A esto llegue prácticamente de forma manual :

```
m=[]
for row in sh_dist:
    if (row[0])== 'A1' and (row[2])== (1.4142135623730951):
        minor = (row[0],row[1],row[2])
        print(minor)
        m.append(minor)
    if (row[0])== 'A2' and (row[2])== (1.000000 ):
        minore = (row[0],row[1],row[2])
        print(minore)
        m.append(minore)
```

Como poder iterar para que recorra la columna[0] A1, hasta que cambie a A2 busque el valor mínimo de la distancia, si hay varios iguales que los incluya y luego pase a A2 y busque nuevamente la menor distancia y asi sucesivamente??

Si hay algún termino mal usado agradeceré la corrección

Desde ya gracias

[image: puntos ploteados]

Comment: Puedes leer la respuesta a esta pregunta: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/347337/c%c3%b3mo-encontrar-el-punto-m%c3%a1s-cercano-de-una-lista-a-en-una-lista-b .

Answer (score 0):

Puedes leer la respuesta a esta pregunta: 
[¿Cómo encontrar el punto más cercano de una lista A en una lista B?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/347337/c%c3%b3mo-encontrar-el-punto-m%c3%a1s-cercano-de-una-lista-a-en-una-lista-b) .

El problema en si era optimizar la función mínima de distancia.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd 
a = {'A': ["A1", "A2","A3"], 'longitud': [19, 25, 34], "latitud": [-99, -100, -120]}
b = {'B': ["B1", "B2","B3"], 'longitud': [17.5, 23.2, 25.8], "latitud": [-100.2, -96, -98.3]}
A = pd.DataFrame(data=a)
B = pd.DataFrame(data=b)

def distancia_i_j(i, j):
    return float(np.sqrt((A[A.A==i].longitud.values-B[B.B==j].longitud.values)**2 + 
                (A[A.A==i].latitud.values-B[B.B==j].latitud.values)**2))

for i in A.A:
    y = [] 
    for j in B.B:
        y.append(distancia_i_j(i,j))
    A.loc[A.A==i, "distancia_min"] = min(y)
```

Igual puedes tratar con:

```
from scipy import spatial

df_a["distancia_min"] = np.min(spatial.distance.cdist(
    df_a[["longitud", "latitud"]], df_b[["longitud", "latitud"]]
    ), axis=1)
```

La libreria scipy me funciono para resolver el mismo problema.

Comment: Saludos, la solución que me has indicado, no me sirve 100%, ya que cuando encuentra dos distancias mínimas iguales, discrimina una y la ídea es que entregue ambas (situación que al parecer no comente), y lo otro es que no entrega el par de puntos, por ejemplos A1 B1 y A2 B3 y un A2 B5, que podría ser la misma distancia que A2 B3